# questions on understanding the function of extracting grobs structure using sapply

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand the following segment, especially the one, `sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name`

```
require(gridExtra)
require(ggplot2)
my_hist <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(my_hist))
leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) ==  "guide-box")
legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
```

I think this function is used to extract the name of `tmp$grobs`, which is shown as follows

[image]

Then I tried. First question, how to understand the structure, like `[[1]]`; further, why `(tmp$grobs[1])$name`  just does not work.

[image]

Comment: Use `[[`: `tmp$grobs[[1]]$name` should work.

Comment: `[1]` doesn't work simply because `tmp` is a list, try `typeof(tmp)`. Please read [this r-faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the). Then, read [this r-faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

Answer (score 2):

this isn't an answer to your question, but a coding suggestion

```
require(ggplot2)
my_hist <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
tmp <- ggplotGrob(my_hist)
legend <- tmp$grobs[[grep("guide-box", tmp$layout$name)]]
```